# Excel: If name in column A matches name in column B, then count number of times text "on time" is present in column C

Tags: excel-formula

**Column A:** list of names
**Column B:** list of names (not in same order as column A)
**Column C:** text "on time" or " Late"
**Column D:** formula entered here - If name in column A matches name in column B, then count number of times text "on time" is present in column C

I have tried sumif, sumifs, countif, countifs,  sumproduct, to no avail. Prefer not to use VBA if at all possible. But will if that is the only solution.

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried?

Comment: Can you post some example data?

Comment: =COUNTIFS(A:A,B:B,C:C,"on time")   =SUMPRODUCT(C3:C25,--(A4:A48),B4:B25)    =SUMIFS(C3:C25,B3:B25,A3:A48)   =SUMIF(A3:A48,B3:B25,C6:C25)      The countifs is the one most closely working for me. It does return a value just not the correct count.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for wanting to help.  The countifs formula just needed tweeking. Changed the reference of B:b first, then A:A and success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find the cell A1 in column B, then count the number of times "on time" is present in Column C if it's found:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE)), "",COUNTIF(C:C, "on time"))
```